# How to Issue a notification according to objects in a listview

Tags: android, android-activity, service, notifications

I have in my `MainActivity` a `listView` containing "Entry" objects, In my entry object I have a function `getDaysLeft()` that returns int,

I want my application to issue a notification whenever the `getDaysLeft()` of any item in the list becomes less than a set threshold.

How do I have the application check for that in the background and issue a notification whenever this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

Checking for timing condition in background is bad idea, it's way better to tell Android "wake up my app tomorrow at 10 AM".

To set up one-time alarm that wakes your app up:

```
AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourapp.package.SOME_ACTION");
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis() 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //24h from now
AM.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
```

Your .package.MyAlarmReceiver class:

```
public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Show a notification here
    }
}
```

Also, you'll need to register your `MyAlarmReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name=".package.MyAlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.yourapp.package.SOME_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In case you've got lot of Entries schedule alarm for nearest notification or two, then in `onReceive` method schedule alarm for next notification and so on, to avoid cluttering AlarmManager.

Comment: Should I place this in 'MainActivity' or where ?

Comment: `MyAlarmReceiver` should be separate class. Code to set up alarm can be called from any place with context access, so `MainActivity` is fine, as is `onReceive`.